# Push to Specific User

Tags: delphi, parse-platform, push-notification, delphi-10-seattle

Writing in Delphi 10 Seattle, targeting the 'pusher' as Windows, and the receiver as iOs (for now). The aim is to be able to push a message to a specific user without relying on broadcast and client side filtering.

I've managed to achieve the following so far:
1. Send a broadcast push to my iOS app
2. Login as a user on my iOS app
3. Create a pointer in my Installation record for User -> _User

That's as far as I can get in Delphi. From what I understand, I have to update the Installation record on login to reflect the installations logged in user.

I cannot find out how to do that in Delphi's Parse/BAAS objects. What seems to be missing is that I can't get the logged in users Installation ID. I assume if I could I could then update that via the TBackendStorage Class.

Any help would be appreciated.

I've cross posted this question to Embarcadero forums and community site.

Comment: Not sure if I get that question right this time, but what about registering the device onto a specific channel (f.i. the user name) and then send pushes to this channel only?

Comment: Whilst following the lead given to me by @Uwe Raabe - I found the answer.

The Installation ID is hidden in the PushEvents object, here is the code which needs to be executed in the DeviceRegistered event of the PushEvents object.:

`if PushEvents.InstallationValue.TryGetObjectID(fInstallationObjectId) then`

Then the following updates the installation object:

`JOP.AddPair('__type','Pointer');
JOP.AddPair('className','_User');
JOP.AddPair('objectId',fUserObjectId);
JO.AddPair('User',JOP);
BackendStorage.Storage.UpdateObject('_Installation',fInstallationObjectId,JO,O);`

Comment: @ChristopherBurke glad you found the solution, and welcome. Did you know you can answer your own question? http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer
If you do so, your answer will be easier to read and you might get further up votes on the answer.

Comment: @BIBD - I did indeed, however there is more information coming which is relevant to the entire solution, I thought it would be useful to everyone to attach it as soon as I finish the details in a couple of days.

Answer (score 1):

**To retrieve the User Object Id**

```
var
  ACreatedObject: TBackendEntityValue; // REST.Backend.MetaTypes
begin
  BackendUsers.Users.LoginUser('donald','#duck99',ACreatedObject);
  fUserObjectId:=ACreatedObject.ObjectID;
end
```

**To Update the Installation with the User Object iD**

Assuming you have a column 'User' in your Installation table on Parse as a pointer to _User class.

Within the *PushEventsDeviceRegistered* Event:

```
var
  JO,JOP:TJSonObject;     // System.JSON
  O:TBackendEntityValue;  // REST.Backend.MetaTypes
begin
  if PushEvents.InstallationValue.TryGetObjectID(fInstallationObjectId) then
  begin
    try
      JO:=TJSONObject.Create;
      JOP:=TJSONObject.Create;
      JOP.AddPair('__type','Pointer');
      JOP.AddPair('className','_User');
      JOP.AddPair('objectId',fUserObjectId);
      JO.AddPair('User',JOP);
      BackendStorage.Storage.UpdateObject('_Installation',
                            fInstallationObjectId,JO,O);
    finally
      JO.Free;
    end;
  end
end;
```

**To Target the Push Message Based on User Name**

Note, you could create the target via JSON objects,but I've used a string with formatting here.

```
const
  Target = '{"where":{"User":{"$select":{"query":'+
           '{"__type":"Pointer","className":"_User","where":'+          
           '{"username":"%s"}},"key":"objectId"}}}}';
begin
  BackendPush.Target.Text:=Format(Target,['donald']);
  BackendPush.Message:='Gratz on the Election Result';
  BackendPush.Push;
end
```

**Non Local Variables/Declarations**

The following Delphi BaaS components were created at Design time.

```
ParseProvider: TParseProvider;
PushEvents: TPushEvents;
BackendUsers: TBackendUsers;
BackendStorage: TBackendStorage;
BackendPush: TBackendPush;
```

The following class (or global) variables are referred to:

```
fUserObjectId:string; // Must be set before push registration is activated.
fInstallationObjectId:string;
```

NOTE: The original code is fully tested, however I've cut/paste (and edited to remove non-relevant stuff) so forgive me if there are any cut/paste errors.